Improve C# LINQ query to get the most suitable range among items (based on a condition)
I've got a List with 5 SubItems each.
List consist of ~2 million of records.
These records/items are already sorted/ordered for next queries.
I've got two tasks:

Find the best continuous range of items, where from a constant count of items (e.g. 20 000) there will be the highest count of items having SubItem[5] not empty, e.g. in range 1-20001 there are 1500 non-empty SubItem[5], but in range 243565-263565 there are 1950 non-empty SubItem[5] - so it is better
Find the best continuous range of items, where for e.g. 10 000 non-empty SubItem[5] global items count will be the smallest. E.g. I've got 10 000 non-empty SubItem[5] in range 1-52346, but I can find the same 10 000 non-empty SubItem[5] in range 355643-381625 (25 982 items), so this range is better

I've made a following attempt to solve 1:
int itmcnt = 0;

while (itmcnt < arrayItems.Count)
{
    var test = from lvi in arrayItems.Skip(itmcnt).Take(20000) where lvi.SubItems[5].Text.Length > 0 select lvi;
    result += test.Count().ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    itmcnt++;
}

So - I'm setting up a counter and while I'm below overall count of items - I'm querying next 20 000 items for a non-empty SubItem[5]. Finally I'm pushing counter and running query again, but starting +1 item (range 1-200001, 2-200002, etc.)
This will probably crash when I will try to Take 20000 items where there won't be that much left, but I even didn't get to that point, because of performance.
When querying only 100 000 items - it takes 135 seconds at my machine. And I need to query 20 times more items...
What I can improve? I feel that querying again an again ranges with +1 start/end is the bottleneck here, but it seems that my LINQ skills are much too limited, to solve this :(
Or maybe the logical idea here is wrong and it would be more efficient to: calculate result for first range (1-20001) and then check SubItem[5] for item 1 (to remove it from result) and 20002 to add it, based on this update result for new range - instead of querying 20k of items, just move along items?

Update - being a bit cheered with help from comment from Kirill Polishchuk (thanks!) I've decided to go along the 'sliding window' approach for task 1 and this turned out to be fully successfull :)
Now I got the result in a less than 1s.
Just to leave the code, maybe sobedoby someday will run into some similar case - this is what I did:
// do just one query
var test = from lvi in arrayItems.Take((int)nudExpTarget.Value) where lvi.SubItems[5].Text != "" select lvi;
// some variables to hold the results
int startingResult = test.Count();
int highest = test.Count();
int highestId = 0;
int itmcnt = 0;

// going through the items
while (itmcnt < arrayItems.Count)
{
    // if we're leaving item, which was useful - decrease the counter
    if (arrayItems[itmcnt].SubItems[5].Text != "")
    {
        startingResult--;
    }
    // check to avoid a query for non-existant item
    if (20000 + itmcnt < arrayItems.Count)
    {
        // if we're adding new useful item - increase counter
        if (arrayItems[20000 + itmcnt].SubItems[5].Text != "")
        {
            startingResult++;
        }
    }
    // update variables with results, if result is better
    if (startingResult > highest)
    {
        highest = startingResult;
        highestId = itmcnt;
    }
    // next item, please
    itmcnt++;
}
// do something with highestId and highest value

Now I'm fighting with a logical approach for task 2.
I've started with something like this, but again ended up with performance issues.
// some variables to hold results
int itmscnt = arrayItems.Count;
int itmid = 0;

// get all useful items - idea is to move through useful items only
var test = from lvi in arrayItems where lvi.SubItems[5].Text != "" select lvi;

// go through selected items
for (int i = 0; i < test.Count(); i++)
{
    // take 20 000 items from the complete result - this seems to be too slow
    var targetanalyze = test.Skip(i).Take(20000);
    // retrieve counters from SubItem[0]
    int targetcnt = Int32.Parse(targetanalyze.Last().SubItems[0].Text) - Int32.Parse(targetanalyze.First().SubItems[0].Text);
    // compare
    if (targetcnt < itmscnt)
    {
        itmscnt = targetcnt;
        itmid = i;
    }
}


"Or maybe the logical idea here is wrong and it would be more efficient to: calculate result for first range (1-20001) and then check SubItem[5] for item 1 (to remove it from result) and 20002 to add it, based on this update result for new range" -- this is so called "sliding window" and will be the most efficient approach. Forget about LINQ in this case :)

Task 2 would benefit from a minimal, reproducible example, maybe by creating random values (starting with a seed to make it reproducible) and also show the expected result.
I am not clear what you need. Your description talks about the sixth item being not blank, but your example is parsing the first item as an integer.

Ignoring your example and using your description, I would suggest iterating through the list to get a running count of the number of matches with the list index.
Then produce a dictionary with count as key and the lowest index as value.
Then you can start with the first match and it is fast to look up the dictionary for count=1 and count=20001 to find the indexes of the matching records and so get the range size.
Repeat for each count and sort the results by size and take the first.
Using Linq, it may not run in less than 1s, I would guess it won't take more than a few seconds.

Thanks @sgmoore :) Your idea was the best - to prepare a 'helper' index. The first column in the source is item index. I've made a list with indexes, which are matching the condition and I'm taking next 20000 items. Result of last index - first index gives me the overall count - now I'm just saving the lowest count and corresponding starting index - the puzzle is solved :) Thanks once again sgmoore and also Kirill Polishchuk - thinking out of the box instead of focusing on one solution was the key here :)
